# How to display a very delayed success message after async method call in WinForms after Form is closed

Tags: asynchronous-programming, winforms

The users are on a Windows Form where they fill out a fax cover sheet and hit Send. The remote fax service takes anywhere from two seconds to two minutes to return a result (long timeout).  By that time, the users have moved on to other things, having closed the form and opened another.

What is the proper way to invoke the async method so that whatever form the users happen to have open, they will eventually see the success or the failure message?

Comment: A `BackgroundWorker` is probably the best fit here.

Comment: But where would the `RunWorkerCompleted` listeners reside, if the form that launches the worker gets closed while the worker is working?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500563/winform-multithreading-use-backgroundworker-or-not

Comment: You need to launch the Background worker in a context where it's going to be able to write to a visible form.  You basically just asked me "How do I display status in a form that is closed?"

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I'm not being obtuse, just ignorant. Where would such a context be? Does the app have to be rewritten as MDI?

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` and `RunWorkerCompleted` are just objects, like any other object.  Treat them accordingly.  Expose some public properties in your base form for them, and assign them to the base form.